# How to mock feature toggle without connection to Launch Darkly?

Tags: python, unit-testing, launchdarkly

I have a new code line which has to be surrounded with a feature toggle.   Since it is a service (Flask application) which initiates all its connections and relevant integration with external sources on the start-up - I have no instance of LaunchDarkly running when executing unit-tests.

Is there a simple way to mock and predefine a feature toggle for unit-tests/integration-tests in Python? I am using pytest for writing the unit-tests.

Example of my code:

```
if FeatureToggle.is_enabled("my-feature-toggle-name"):
     *my code logic*
```

the `is_enabled()` method impl:

```
@staticmethod
def is_enabled(flag_name: str, user_key: str=None, custom_params: dict=None) -> bool:
    if user_key is None:
        user_key = 'defaut_user_key'

    return FeatureToggle.ld_client.variation(flag_name, {"key": user_key, "custom": custom_params}, False)
```

When running the application `FeatureToggle.ld_client` is initiated with a proper api-key to launch darkly and then allows me to use their `variation()` method.
I understand that I can change my `is_enabled()` method to return predefined value when there is not instance of `ld_client` but I am looking for more elegant way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investigating and advising my colleagues this can be done by using [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) library.

I will update the answer when I will have full working solution

Comment: So, have you found one?

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that in addition to using a mocking library, you can also instantiate the client to read from a file[1] instead of connecting to the LaunchDarkly API. This way you can have a pre-determined set of test values that you can use for testing purposes.

[1] https://launchdarkly-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-integrations.html?highlight=test#ldclient.integrations.Files